# Svm Predict next number in sequence

Tags: r, svm, predict

I was asked to compare an svm model to a linear regression model to determine difference in predictions. Input data (x) is 0 to 8, i create a "label" in the next column that represents the class of next value (y), and then i try to see how the svm performs. It actually works fine for inputs from 0 to 7 but then it doesnt work ok. Can i improve this or svm is limited because of the sequential data? 
My code:

```
library(e1071)
Dataset <-data.frame("x"=c(0:8),"y"=c(1:9))
test=data.frame("x"=c(0:15))
mymodel<-svm(y~x, data=Dataset)
pred<- predict(mymodel,test)
table(Predicted = pred,test$x)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods such as SVM, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. But in general trying to predict outside the range on which you trained your data is not a good idea.

Comment: kernel="linear" did the trick and now it predicts fine other values that were not in the training set. Thanks.